# Should we protect web application source code from being stolen by web hosts through obfuscation?

Tags: java, legal

Is it worth to obfuscate a java web app source code so that the web host cannot make wrong use of the code & probably even steal your business. If, so how to deal with this or how to obfuscate ?

We are just a new start up launching a product in market. How can we protect our product/ web application source code ?